# Running jQuery on a custom page in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I have looked at several related help topics but I am still missing an important step.  I have created a new page...page--employee.tpl.php   This page contains three tabs that currently load three separate 'pages'. The html on page--employee.tpl.php is as follows:

```
<div id="a" class="empTab"><a href="/"><span>Employee Home</span></a></div>
<div id="b" class="empTab"><a href="/"><span>State Notices</span></a></div>
<div id="c" class="empTab"><a href="/"><span>Federal Notices</span></a></div>
```

I am trying to implement a very simple .click function so that when a user clicks on tab a...tab a gets the .activeTab class.  When they click on b...b gets the activeTab class and the same with c.  My jQuery works locally, but I don't know where to put it on my custom page--employee.tpl.php  When I put my jQuery code in the html template file, it works until my custom page loads and then the html executes as above and the a tab get the .activeTab class even though the user has clicked on the b tab.  Can anyone shed some light on this topic?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this module. 
http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs

The Quick Tabs module allows you to create blocks of tabbed content, specifically views, blocks, nodes* and other quicktabs*. You can create a block on your site containing multiple tabs with corresponding content. Clicking on the tabs makes the corresponding content display instantly, using jQuery. With the 6.x-2.x branch, this can be done in either ajax or non-ajax mode:

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I am aware of the Tabs module and totally agree with you.  The site I am working on headed down the road of js so I thought I would continue as I had a time constraint.  Even though the Tab module is the best answer, if I wanted to run my own animation code on a custom page for instance, where would this code go?  Outside of Drupal, I would just stick it in the header between script tags.